# Swig Templates List Item Number

Tags: javascript, templates, swig-template

I can't figure out how you print the number of the list item using swig templates. Example( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ).

```
<ul>
  {% for result in results %}
  <li>
    <span>Item number: {{n}}</span>
    {{ result.title }}
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer under the “Task #1” heading on this page:

- http://bits.shutterstock.com/2013/03/07/mustache-vs-swig-templating-shootout/

Specifically, within `{% for %}` tags in Swig, you have access to a variable called `loop`, which has an `index` property:

```
<ul>
  {% for result in results %}
  <li>
    <span>Item number: {{ loop.index }}</span>
    {{ result.title }}
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

See also the Swig docs: http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/tags/#for